# Extending figures into the margin on even vs. odd pages

Tags: floats, positioning, koma-script, double-sided

I am using KOMA script for my document.  Occasionally, I have a float that is wider than text width, and I want the float to be pushed into the **outer** margin.  This is why I defined `\widefloat` command, that checks if page is odd using command `\ifthispageodd` and depending on the results pushes the float left or right.  This works fine when float is in the middle of the page.  However, when float is thrown into the next page, `\ifthispageodd` gives wrong result.  Could you please tell me how to fix this up?

MWE: the first float is correctly pushed into outer margin, the second is pushed into inner margin.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}

\newcommand{\widefloat}[1]{%
\ifthispageodd{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{#1}}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\widefloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (16cm,10cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\lipsum[3]

\widefloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (16cm,10cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem arises because the `\ifthispageodd` first writes a `\label` to the `.aux` file and then (essentially) does a `\pageref` of the label to get the current page. Unfortunately, the label and the reference can get separated from each other and from the figure you are placing. One way to prevent this is to wrap the whole thing in an `\mbox`:

```
\newcommand{\widefloat}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    \ifthispageodd%
    {%
      \makebox[\textwidth][l]{#1}%
    }{%
      \makebox[\textwidth][r]{#1}
    }
  }%
}
```

You might also want to put `\noindent` in front of `\mbox` to get proper margin alignment.

Comment: I wonder... which solution is in your opinion more economical in terms of resources and compiling times?

Comment: @Pygmalion Well, adding a box around a figure should add only microscopicly to the time and memory used. On the other hand, the `calc` package doesn't add a great deal compared to what LaTex consumes all by itself.

Answer (score 7):

This happens because when the second `\widefloat` is issued, the page is still odd...

Define it as

```
\newcommand{\widefloat}[1]{%
\setlength{\alength}{\textheight-\pagetotal}%
\setlength{\blength}{\totalheightof{\parbox{\linewidth}{#1}}}%
\ifdim\alength<\blength\clearpage\fi%
\ifthispageodd{\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{#1}}{\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][r]{#1}}%
}
```

and add

```
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\alength}
\newlength{\blength}
```

in your preamble, so that your MWE becomes

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\alength}
\newlength{\blength}

\newcommand{\widefloat}[1]{%
\setlength{\alength}{\textheight-\pagetotal}%
\setlength{\blength}{\totalheightof{\parbox{\linewidth}{#1}}}%
\ifdim\alength<\blength\clearpage\fi%
\ifthispageodd{\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{#1}}{\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][r]{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\widefloat{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (16cm,10cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\lipsum[3]

\widefloat{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (16cm,10cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I know I am a bit tedious, but is it possible to perform that without using `calc` package.  I avoid additional packages, if possible.

Comment: @Pygmalion Unfortunately `\totalheightof` comes from `calc` package and it is the mainstay of the code...