# Avoid conflict between marginpar and full width figure

Tags: memoir, marginpar

I am working on a document (`memoir` class) where I use `marginpar` for citations.

I also use full width figures (i.e. figures that run into the margin, such that they are symmetric wrt to the center of the page). Similar to this: [Extending figures into the margin on even vs. odd pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140739/extending-figures-into-the-margin-on-even-vs-odd-pages?rq=1)

Unfortunately, when I have several citations in the margin and a full width figure, sometimes the margin notes run into the figure. Is there a way to prevent `marginpar` from using part of the page (such that it shifts the marginpars up, instead of down)?

See MWE below.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmarginnotes{0.15in}{1.35in}{\baselineskip}
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5in}{1.0in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\reversemarginpar

\usepackage[hyperref=true,style=numeric-comp,
    giveninits=true,backref,autocite=superscript,
    sorting=none]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro{sidecite}{%
  \scriptsize%
  \printfield{labelnumber}.
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printfield{year}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\mcite}
  {}
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\textsuperscript{\printfield{labelnumber}}}%
    \marginpar{\usebibmacro{sidecite}}%
   }
  {}
  {}

% Full-width figure
\newlength\marginextra\marginextra=1.5in
\newlength\fullwidth\fullwidth=\textwidth
\advance\fullwidth by \marginextra

\newcounter{fullfigcnt}

\newenvironment{fullfigure}[1][]
  {\begin{figure}[#1]%
      \ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{fullfigs:\thefullfigcnt}}}%
      {\begin{adjustwidth}{-\marginextra}{0cm}}%
      {\begin{adjustwidth}{0cm}{-\marginextra}}%
  }%
  {\end{adjustwidth}%
    \label{fullfigs:\thefullfigcnt}\end{figure}\stepcounter{fullfigcnt}%
  }

% MWE
\usepackage{mwe}

% bib-file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knu86,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX book},
}
@BOOK{KandR,
  AUTHOR    = {Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.},
  TITLE     = {{The C Programming Language Second Edition}},
  PUBLISHER = {Prentice-Hall, Inc.},
  YEAR      = {1988},
}
@book{Gladwell2005,
    author = {Gladwell, Malcolm},
    address = {New York, NY},
    publisher = {Back Bay Books},
    title = {Blink: The Power of Thinking Without Thinking},
    year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] All hail Knuth.\mcite{Knu86} \TeX\ is hard,\mcite{KandR} but not impossible.\mcite{Gladwell2005}

\begin{fullfigure}[h]
    \hfill\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Large figure.}
\end{fullfigure}

\lipsum[2-3] 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Citations conflicting with image]

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example that others can test as is. For images, you can use the ones provided along with the mwe package on ctan. As your question is now, people need to guess what you're doing, and they often do not have time for that. So help us help you.

Comment: You could put a full width figure into a \marginpar, but probably not using whatever package you are currently using.  Then you have the problem of leaving space blank in the text area.

Comment: @daleif I figured there would be an easy solution, but I guess there is not. MWE is added. Thanks

Comment: Even though the msrginspars are also floats, since the normally occupy different areas, full width floats does not take marginpars into account. There is not much you can do here other than manually move the full width figure out of the way. Btw this is not a memoir feature, I'll happen in all document classes.

Comment: Yes, it will happen in all classes. I was just wondering if you could somehow add a marginpar over the whole height of the figure (which is empty) such that the other marginpars get moved around. But I guess I'll stick to the manual version.

Comment: You could probably cheat by adding a marginpar with a zero width rule in it (a specially crafted strut), but it will be a very hand held solution. I'd probably only allow these very wide figures at the top of the page, aka loosing the `h` and using `tp` then there should not be any overlap as the image will be on a page of its own or at the top of the page where there hasn't been added any marginpars yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, enclosing the figure with `\blockmargin`
`\unblockmargin` did the trick for me. These commands are part of the `marginfix` package.